# python, convert a dictionary to a sorted list by value instead of key

Tags: python, sorting

I have a collections.defaultdict(int) that I'm building to keep count of how many times a key shows up in a set of data. I later want to be able to sort it (obviously by turning it into a list first) in a descending fashion, ordered with the highest values first. I created my dictionary like the following:

```
adict = defaultdict(int)
```

later on I do a bunch of:

```
adict['someval'] += 1
adict['anotherval'] +=1
adict['someval'] += 1
```

Ideally after that I'd like to get a print out of:

```
someval => 2
anotherval => 1
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

A dict's keys, reverse-sorted by the corresponding values, can best be gotten as

```
sorted(adict, key=adict.get, reverse=True)
```

since you want key/value pairs, you could work on the items as all other answers suggest, or (to use the nifty `adict.get` bound method instead of itemgetters or weird lambdas;-),

```
[(k, adict[k]) for k in sorted(adict, key=adict.get, reverse=True)]
```

**Edit**: in terms of performance, there isn't much into it either way:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s'adict=dict((x,x**2) for x in range(-5,6))' '[(k, adict[k]) for k in sorted(adict, key=adict.get, reverse=True)]'
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.8 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s'adict=dict((x,x**2) for x in range(-5,6)); from operator import itemgetter' 'sorted(adict.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)'
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.66 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s'adict=dict((x,x**2) for x in range(-5,6))' 'sorted(adict.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v): v, reverse=True)'
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.5 usec per loop
```

So, the `.get`-based solution is smack midway in performance between the two `items`-based ones -- slightly slower than the `itemgetter`, slightly faster than the `lambda`. In "bottleneck" cases, where those microsecond fractions are crucial to you, by all means do focus on that. In normal cases, where this operation is only one step within some bigger task and a microsecond more or less matters little, focusing on the simplicity of the `get` idiom is, however, also a reasonable alternative.

Comment: `adict.get` variant does key lookup twice for each item the dict. `[(k, v) for k, v in sorted(adict.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)]` does it once.

Comment: If you wanted keys with the same value sorted as well, is there something better than a "wierd lambda"?

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: for that matter, you can drop the list comprehension stuff and just use: `sorted(adict.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)`. Like Nadia does.

Comment: Found it, using itemgetter(1, 0) does the same as lambda (k, v): (v, k) and an order of magnitude faster.

Comment: **Warning to readers in 2019+:** Python 3 does not use `iteritems` anymore. Comments above are 10 years old. Furthermore, if you want a list of keys sorted by their value (and you don't care about the value), just use `sorted(foo, key=foo.get)`. It returns a list of the keys sorted by their value. If you just do `sorted(foo)` you get all keys sorted by key, and by adding `key=foo.get` you tell the sorter to sort those keys by the dictionary VALUE of each key instead. Either way the `sorted()` function only returns the keys from the dictionary.

Answer (score 43):

To get the dictionary sorted:

```
from operator import itemgetter

sorted(adict.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 7):

Just sort the resulting dict by values:

```
for k, v in sorted(adict.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1], reverse=True):
    print("%s => %s" % (k,v))
```

Answer (score 3):

*Note: I'm putting this in as an answer so that it gets seen. I don't want upvotes. If you want to upvote anyone, upvote Nadia.*

**The *currently* accepted answer gives timing results which are based on a trivially small dataset** (size == 6 - (-5) == 11). The differences in cost of the various methods are masked by the overhead. A use case like what are the most frequent words in a text or most frequent names in a membership list or census involves much larger datasets.

Repeating the experiment with range(-n,n+1) (Windows box, Python 2.6.4, all times in microseconds):

n=5: 11.5, 9.34, 11.3
n=50: 65.5, 46.2, 68.1
n=500: 612, 423, 614

**These results are NOT "slightly" different.** **The itemgetter answer is a clear winner on speed.**

There was also mention of "**the simplicity of the `get` idiom**". Putting them close together for ease of comparison:

`[(k, adict[k]) for k in sorted(adict, key=adict.get, reverse=True)]`
`sorted(adict.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)`

The `get` idiom not only looks up the dict twice (as J. F. Sebastian has pointed out), it makes one list (result of `sorted()`) then iterates over that list to create a result list. I'd call that **baroque, not simple**. YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import defaultdict
adict = defaultdict(int)

adict['a'] += 1
adict['b'] += 3
adict['c'] += 5
adict['d'] += 2

for key, value in sorted(adict.items(), lambda a, b: cmp(a[1], b[1]), reverse=True):
    print "%r => %r" % (key, value)

>>> 
'c' => 5
'b' => 3
'd' => 2
'a' => 1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the newest python 2.7 alpha, then you can use the [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class in collections module:

```
c = Counter()

c['someval'] += 1
c['anotherval'] += 1
c['someval'] += 1

print c.most_common()
```

prints in the correct order:

```
[('someval', 2), ('anotherval', 1)]
```

The code used on 2.7 is [available already](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/collections.py?view=markup) and there's a version [adapted to 2.5](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611/). Perhaps you want to use it to stay forward compatible with the native stdlib version that is about to be released.

Answer (score 0):

"Invert" a dictionary.

```
from collections import defaultdict
inv_dict = defaultdict( list )
for key, value in adict:
    inv_dict[value].append( key )
max_value= max( inv_dict.keys() )
```

The set of keys with the maximum occurrence --

```
inv_dict[max_value]
```

The set of keys in descending order by occurrence --

```
for value, key_list in sorted( inv_dict ):
    print key_list, value
```