# Weird output from .itemgetter for list sorting by values python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

So I'm working on the [Google Python Code Class](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/) and attempting to do the Word_Count.py exercise. The aim is to create a dictionary of words (key) sorted by word count (value) and return them as tuples for printing.

I've created a helper function to create my dictionary:

```
def dict_creator(filename): #helper function to create a dictionary each 'word' is a key and the 'wordcount' is the value
            input_file = open(filename, 'r') #open file as read
            for line in input_file: #for each line of text in the input file
                    words = line.split() #split each line into individual words
                    for word in words: #for each word in the words list(?)
                            word = word.lower() #make each word lower case.
                            if word not in word_count: #if the word hasn't been seen before
                                    word_count[word] = 1 #create a dictionary key with the 'word' and assign a value of 1
                            else: word_count[word] += 1 #if 'word' seen before, increase value by 1
            return word_count #return word_count dictionary
            word_count.close()
```

I'm now in the process of creating the dictionary sorted by value (largest to smallest) using the .itemgetter method outlined in this post here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1915602/1842478). Here is my code:

```
def print_words(filename):
        word_count = dict_creator(filename) #run dict_creator on input file (creating dictionary)
        print sorted(word_count.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
        #print dictionary in total sorted descending by value. Values have been doubled compared to original dictionary?
        for word in sorted(word_count.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True):
                #create sorted list of tuples using operator module functions sorted in an inverse manner
                a = word
                b = word_count[word]
                print a, b #print key and value
```

However, when I run the code on the test file and also on a smaller file it throws a key error (shown below).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Misc\google-python-exercises\basic\wordcount_edited.py", line 74, in <module>
    print_words(lorem_ipsum) #run input file through print_words
  File "F:\Misc\google-python-exercises\basic\wordcount_edited.py", line 70, in print_words
    b = word_count[word]
KeyError: ('in', 3)
```

I've printed the original dictionary and the sorted dictionary and it appears all the values have been doubled when the dictionary has been sorted. I've looked through several threads related to this sort of issue and checked the .itemgetter documentation, however I can't seem to find anyone else with a similar issue.

Could anyone point out what's causing my code to iterate over the dictionary a second time in the word_count function which causes the increase in the values?

Thanks!

SB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) You don't actually define `word_count` in `dict_creator`.  I was expecting to see

```
word_count = {}
```

at the start.  This means that whatever `word_count` it's changing is defined elsewhere and global, so whenever you call `dict_creator` it'll add to the same `word_count` dictionary, increasing the values.  You only ever have one `word_count`, at least from the code you've shown.

(2) As for the KeyError:

```
   for word in sorted(word_count.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True):
            #create sorted list of tuples using operator module functions sorted in an inverse manner
            a = word
            b = word_count[word]
```

`iteritems()` returns the tuples, so `word` is already something like `('dict_creator', 1)`.  You can simply print it as it is.  Calling `word_count[word]` tries to use the tuple of `(key, value)` as the key.  IOW, even though you've called the variable word, it's really `word_and_count`, with `word, count = word_and_count`.

(3) In this part:

```
        return word_count #return word_count dictionary
        word_count.close()
```

I think you mean `input_file.close()`, but there's no point in closing the file "after" you return, because that line won't be executed.  Another option is to use the `with` idiom:

```
with open(filename) as input_file:
    code_goes_here = True
return word_count
```

here the file will automatically be closed.

After making the above changes, your code seems to work for me.

Comment: Ah yes, I do have a 'word_count = {}' but it's above the 'dict_creator' function. Would I be better putting it into the function proper then?

Comment: @s_boardman: well, if you don't, then every time you call `dict_creator` -- which doesn't create a dict :^) -- you'll be using the same dictionary.  If you call `dict_creator` twice on the same file, the values will be doubles.  If you call it on two separate files, you'll get the combined totals.

Comment: That makes so much more sense! Thanks very much for all the help. :)